# How to set key to query result?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following request in Laravel:

```
$name = Place::where("status", "1", function ($query) use ($request) {

            if (($from = $request->get("from"))) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', $from . '%');
            }

            if (($to = $request->get("to"))) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', $to . '%');
            }

        })->orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
```

I get result like as:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Lena"
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Baran"
}
```

How can I set keys for these two result rows? I want to do:

```
 name_one = {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Lena"
    },
    name_two = {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Baran"
    }
```

Comment: $ss = array('name_one','name_two');   $res = array_combine($ss,json_decode($your_array,true));  print_r($res);

Comment: `$name` is collection

Comment: its look like json data but its not valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
    public function getCollectinos()
    {
        $collection = collect([
            ['id' => '1', 'product' => 'Chair'],
            ['id' => '2', 'product' => 'Desk'],
            ['id' => '3', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
        ]);


        $grouped = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
            return  'name_'.$this->number_to_word($item['id']);
        });

        $array = $grouped->toArray();
        dd($array);
    }    



     public function number_to_word( $num = '' )
    {
        $num    = ( string ) ( ( int ) $num );

        if( ( int ) ( $num ) && ctype_digit( $num ) )
        {
            $words  = array( );

            $num    = str_replace( array( ',' , ' ' ) , '' , trim( $num ) );

            $list1  = array('','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven',
                'eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen',
                'fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen');

            $list2  = array('','ten','twenty','thirty','forty','fifty','sixty',
                'seventy','eighty','ninety','hundred');

            $list3  = array('','thousand','million','billion','trillion',
                'quadrillion','quintillion','sextillion','septillion',
                'octillion','nonillion','decillion','undecillion',
                'duodecillion','tredecillion','quattuordecillion',
                'quindecillion','sexdecillion','septendecillion',
                'octodecillion','novemdecillion','vigintillion');

            $num_length = strlen( $num );
            $levels = ( int ) ( ( $num_length + 2 ) / 3 );
            $max_length = $levels * 3;
            $num    = substr( '00'.$num , -$max_length );
            $num_levels = str_split( $num , 3 );

            foreach( $num_levels as $num_part )
            {
                $levels--;
                $hundreds   = ( int ) ( $num_part / 100 );
                $hundreds   = ( $hundreds ? ' ' . $list1[$hundreds] . ' Hundred' . ( $hundreds == 1 ? '' : 's' ) . ' ' : '' );
                $tens       = ( int ) ( $num_part % 100 );
                $singles    = '';

                if( $tens < 20 )
                {
                    $tens   = ( $tens ? ' ' . $list1[$tens] . ' ' : '' );
                }
                else
                {
                    $tens   = ( int ) ( $tens / 10 );
                    $tens   = ' ' . $list2[$tens] . ' ';
                    $singles    = ( int ) ( $num_part % 10 );
                    $singles    = ' ' . $list1[$singles] . ' ';
                }
                $words[]    = $hundreds . $tens . $singles . ( ( $levels && ( int ) ( $num_part ) ) ? ' ' . $list3[$levels] . ' ' : '' );
            }

            $commas = count( $words );

            if( $commas > 1 )
            {
                $commas = $commas - 1;
            }

            $words  = implode( ', ' , $words );

            $words  = trim(str_replace( ' ,' , ',' , $this->trim_all(  $words  ) ) , ', ');
            if( $commas )
            {
                $words  = $this->str_replace_last( ',' , ' and' , $words );
            }

            return $words;
        }
        else if( ! ( ( int ) $num ) )
        {
            return 'Zero';
        }
        return '';
    }


   public function str_replace_last( $search , $replace , $str ) 
   {
        if( ( $pos = strrpos( $str , $search ) ) !== false ) {
            $search_length  = strlen( $search );
            $str    = substr_replace( $str , $replace , $pos , $search_length );
        }
        return $str;
    }


    public function trim_all( $str , $what = NULL , $with = ' ' )
    {
        if( $what === NULL )
        {
            //  Character      Decimal      Use
            //  "\0"            0           Null Character
            //  "\t"            9           Tab
            //  "\n"           10           New line
            //  "\x0B"         11           Vertical Tab
            //  "\r"           13           New Line in Mac
            //  " "            32           Space

            $what   = "\\x00-\\x20";    //all white-spaces and control chars
        }

        return trim( preg_replace( "/[".$what."]+/" , $with , $str ) , $what );
    }
```

Output  :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do a `keyBy('name');` after the `get()` function lookup keyBy example below

```
$collection = collect([
    ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'desk'],
    ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'chair'],
]);

$keyed = $collection->keyBy('product_id');

$keyed->all();

/*
    [
        'prod-100' => ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
        'prod-200' => ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
    ]
*/
```